# How do you adjust the cache duration of a statically bound rendering in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore, I have a statically-bound renderer in my Razor:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("[item ID]")
```

This works great, but I want to cache.  So:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("[item ID]", new { Cacheable = true } )
```

This also works, and seems to cache for about 60 seconds, which I understand is the default.

I'd like to cache for 20 minutes (1200 seconds), but I can't find any way to specify this.  That second param to `Rendering` is an anonymous object, so there's not help from Intellisense around that.  I've tried:

```
new { Cacheable = true, Duration = 1200 }
new { Cacheable = true, Cache_Duration = 1200 } // Someone said Cache_ was the trick. It wasn't.
```

What is the setting to vary the cache duration of these renderings?

**Update**

I reflected a bit, but to no avail.  The properties on that anonymous object are iterated and used to set values on `Rendering.RenderingProperties`. This is a key/value data structure, keyed by string, so any cache settings are no longer strongly-typed, and thus my reflecting trail ran cold.

**Another Update**

@sitecore-climber did some more reflecting, and found a property of `RenderingCachingDefiniton` called `Timeout` which appears to parse the value of the `Cache_Timeout` key into a `Timespan` object.

However, my actual testing of this...

```
new { Cacheable = true, Cache_Timeout = "00:20:00"}
```

...doesn't seem to change the 60-second caching timeout.  This is odd, since you can see all the other properties in the `RenderingCachingDefinition` class that parse off that anonymous object parameter (`Cacheable`, `VaryByParam`, etc.).

Of course, this might be parsing just fine, and Sitecore just doesn't do anything with the resulting value.  But I followed that `Timeout` property around, and based on my reading, it's accurately used to set a timeout on the cache.

Comment: I don't think it's working out of the box. Can you check this solution. http://reinoudvandalen.nl/blog/add-sliding-expiration-on-sitecore-rendering-cache/

Comment: Can you try with Cache_Timeout? I decompile the code and TimeOut property looks like:  TimeSpan result;
        if (TimeSpan.TryParse(this.Rendering["Cache_Timeout"], out result))
          return result;

Comment: Yes, I found that same code. I have tried it, and it doesn't seem to work.  I put `00:20:00` in there which should accurately parse to 20 minutes.  My testing procedure: I have a line in my Razor template of `@DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()`.  I can hit refresh over and over, and it still changes about every 60 seconds.

Comment: I wonder if it has to be done in the pipelines? http://reinoudvandalen.nl/blog/add-sliding-expiration-on-sitecore-rendering-cache/

Comment: I tried that too, but I'm not sure statically bound items ever hit the pipeline. That sounds weird, I know, but stuck a step in the pipeline with a breakpoint and watched everything come through. As near as I could tell, my four statically bound renderers never came through.

Comment: @Deane Statically bound renderers should go through the pipeline as well. Did you clear your caches from `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx` before refreshing the page? You may want to try the [Sitecore Cache Admin](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/S/Sitecore_Cache_Admin.aspx) to take a closer look what and how it is being stored in cache.

Comment: @jammykam It's weird. The `args.Rendering.Item` is not the rendering, but it rather the page the rendering appears on.  However, `args.Rendering.RenderingItemPath` is the ID of the rendering item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried on a Sitecore 8.1 solution and is working fine using

@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{240A3624-8600-4A7B-8C07-5846A673F1F0}", new { Cacheable = true,Cache_Timeout = "00:20:00" } )

On my view container I have :

```
 @Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{240A3624-8600-4A7B-8C07-5846A673F1F0}")

 @Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{240A3624-8600-4A7B-8C07-5846A673F1F0}", new { Cacheable = true,Cache_Timeout = "00:20:00" } )
```

My view is very simple

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
<div>
<h1>
    @Html.Sitecore().Field("title")
</h1>
<div>
    @Html.Sitecore().Field("text")
    @System.DateTime.Now.Second
</div>
</div>
```

But caching is working just on normal mode not on experience editor or page editor. Did you try to publish and check your website?

Please check video I uploaded at : https://www.dropbox.com/s/57s5x0zw7yr8lyb/VideoAvi.avi?dl=0

Comment: How did you verify it was working?  I didn't quite understand the video.

Comment: I have @Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{240A3624-8600-4A7B-8C07-5846A673F1F0}")

 @Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{240A3624-8600-4A7B-8C07-5846A673F1F0}", new { Cacheable = true,Cache_Timeout = "00:20:00" } ) and If I''m refreshing the page you can see on first rendering the seconds  are changing and in second view seconds are the same.

Comment: Yes, but will it cache for the 20 minutes?  It will cache for 60 seconds (the default if `Cacheable` is set to `true`).  Come back in 15 minutes, and see if the cache has held.

Comment: I tried your case and is working fine for me. Be carefull if someone is publishing your item, cache is cleared.

Comment: Thank you for testing this. I must have a deeper problem with cache. Maybe the limit is set too low?  Maybe things continue to publish in the background?  Not sure, but this is helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: I was really curious about your issue, because I will need also to cache some renderings in future projects..., glad to help you

Comment: "It will cache for 60 seconds" - I'm not aware of this being the case, Sitecore will always cache HTML until a publish or app pool recycle... There must be something else going on in your solution...